# Where do Zeitler's scale names come from?

Tags: theory, scales, terminology

On Ian Ring's [music theory website](https://ianring.com/musictheory/), a [massive number of scales (1490) have "**Zeitler**" names](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/traditions/zeitler).

Some names are common (like Mixolydian) but others (like Dydyllic) I cannot find any reference to.

Hence my question: **where do these names originate from?** Do they have any meaning or are they made up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These names come from an author named William Zeitler, whose website, AllTheScales, is available [here](https://allthescales.org/).

In his [introduction page](https://allthescales.org/intro.php), in a section titled "The Names of the Modes," he says:

> A curious feature of humans is that a thing seems to be less "real"
> until it has a name. One of the first things done in concentration
> camps to de-humanize the inmates is to expunge their names and replace
> them with numbers. And the only task God gave Adam in the Garden of
> Eden (apart from staying away from the Tree of Knowledge) was to name
> all the animals. And one of the first things human parents do is name
> their new child. The child isn't even officially born (as far as the
> government is concerned) until a name is filled in on the birth
> certificate. And somehow it seems much easier to compose music in the
> "aeolithic mode" than in "mode number 427".
>
> So, it would seem that all the animals in our modal musical garden
> need names. Therefore I have named them. There is at least this
> pattern: all the names of the 5-note names end in "-atonic" (for
> example, the "Pentatonic"), all the names of the 7-note scales end
> in "-ian" (for example, "Dorian"), and so on.

He continues on, but in short, he made them up himself. There's a system to the suffixes, but the base names themselves are really idiosyncratic. (And for what it's worth, I'd never actually heard of these names, or of him, until you asked this question. So my sense is that they're not used all that often.)